# ListFragment chrashes when rotating screen - Android

Tags: java, android

I have a TabLayout with three tabs and each a ListFragment in it. These are handled by a SectionsPagerAdapter. When rotating the screen it seems like they have lost their ListAdapters for they are loading but nothing happens:
[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyN3Y.png)

Actually I have red a lot of stuff about lifecycles concerning fragments but yet I wasn't able to implement it for my problem.

When rotating the screen the activity gets destroyed and onCreate() is called again. So I put the following things there:

1. Create new instance of the ListFragment
2. Create new instance of a CursorAdapter
3. Set the Adapter

So where is my fallacy?

EDIT:
I solved the problem now overriding the `onSaveInstanceState` method. But what exactly is saved there leading to the described problem?

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    FragmentManager mFragmentManager;

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Fragments for the three Tabs
    public Contact fragment_all;
    public Contact fragment_official;
    public Contact fragment_alumni;

    // Handler for SQLite DB Access
    public DBHandler dbhandler;

    private MemberListAdapter ca_all;
    private MemberListAdapter ca_alu;
    private MemberListAdapter ca_off;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_members);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(mFragmentManager);

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        fragment_all = new Contact();
        fragment_alumni = new Contact();
        fragment_official = new Contact();

        dbhandler = new DBHandler(this);
        ca_all = new MemberListAdapter(this);
        ca_alu = new MemberListAdapter(this);
        ca_off = new MemberListAdapter(this);

        ca_all.ID = 1;
        ca_alu.ID = 3;
        ca_off.ID = 2;

        fragment_all.setListAdapter(ca_all);
        fragment_alumni.setListAdapter(ca_alu);
        fragment_official.setListAdapter(ca_off);

        updateAdapters();            
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        dbhandler.close();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // ...unimportant code
    }


    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            if (position == 0){
                return fragment_all;
            }else if (position == 1){
                return fragment_official;
            }else{
                return fragment_alumni;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getResources().getString(R.string.title_section1);

                case 1:
                    return getResources().getString(R.string.title_section2);
                case 2:
                    return getResources().getString(R.string.title_section3);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void updateAdapters() {
        ca_all.changeCursor(dbhandler.query());
        ca_alu.changeCursor(dbhandler.query());
        ca_off.changeCursor(dbhandler.query());
    }
}
```

layout_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/colorSecond">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorContrast"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            android:background="@color/colorContrast"
            android:fillViewport="false"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/updatedb" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

ListFragment Contact.java:

```
public class Contact extends ListFragment {
    private CursorAdapter ca;
    private MemberListAdapter mla;

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
        mla = (MemberListAdapter) getListAdapter();
        String myid = Integer.toString(mla.ID);

        Log.i("Position: ", Integer.toString(position));
        Log.i("ID: ", myid);
    }

    public Contact(){
        super();

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

CursorAdapter MemberListAdapter.java:

```
public class MemberListAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater inflator;
    public int ID;

    public MemberListAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, null, 0);
        inflator = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        int ciName = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHandler.USERS_NAME);
        int ciSurname = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHandler.USERS_SURNAME);
        int ciMail = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHandler.USERS_MAIL);

        String mail = cursor.getString(ciMail);
        String name = cursor.getString(ciName);
        String surname = cursor.getString(ciSurname);

        ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextView textview1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        TextView textview2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text2);

        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ksatlogo);
        textview1.setText(name + ", " + surname);
        textview2.setText(mail);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return inflator.inflate(R.layout.icon_text_text, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show error log ?

Comment: Actually there is none, it simply doesn't load.

Comment: Add debug log messages to your onCreate and onDestroy methods in your activity.  What output do you see when you rotate the device?  Does it match your assumptions about the lifetime of your activity?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding android:configChanges="orientation" in your activity in manifest.